# Insert values from a type list PLSQL ORACLE 11

Tags: oracle, plsql, types, oracle11g

thanks for helping me.
The first insert works OK but the second doesnt insert anything. Can you help me please. Im learning plsql but there is still some things i dont know.

```
PROCEDURE PR_INS_INVESTIGATION (
   PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION  IN IN_INS_INVESTIGATION)
IS
   LST_INS_INVESTIGATED  RC_INS_INVESTIGATED;
   EX_NO_DATA            EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO PQR076INVESTIGATION (CCPQR076IDINVESTIGATION,
                                    CCPQR076DATE,
                                    CCPQR076AREA,
                                    CCPQR076STATE,
                                    CCPQR076USER)
        VALUES (PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION.IDINVESTIGACION,
                SYSDATE,
                PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION.AREA,
                PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION.STATE,
                USER);

   COMMIT;

   IF     LST_INS_INVESTIGATED IS NOT NULL
      AND LST_INS_INVESTIGATED.COUNT > 0
   THEN
      FOR j IN LST_INS_INVESTIGATED.FIRST .. LST_INS_INVESTIGATED.LAST
      LOOP
         INSERT INTO PQR075INVESTIGATED (CCPQR075IDINVESTIGATION,
                                         CCPQR075NIDENT,
                                         CCPQR075NAME,
                                         CCPQR075USER)
              VALUES (PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION.IDINVESTIGAtION,
                      LST_INS_INVESTIGATED (J).NUMBERID,
                      LST_INS_INVESTIGATED (J).NAME,
                      USER);

         COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;
END;
```

This is the way im testing the procedure:

´´´

```
declare
  pin_ins_investigation in_ins_investigation;
begin
  pin_ins_investigation := in_ins_investigation();
  pin_ins_investigation.IDinvestigation := '1234460';
  pin_ins_investigation.AREA := '05';
  pin_ins_investigation.STATE := 'E';
  
  pin_ins_investigation.LST_INS_investigated.extend;
  pin_ins_investigation.LST_INS_investigated(1).NUMBERID := '1014350360';
  pin_ins_investigation.LST_INS_investigated(1).NAME := 'PETER TOSH';
  
 
 
  pkg_package.pr_ins_investigation(pin_ins_investigation => pin_ins_investigation);
                                     
end;
```

´´´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, this:

```
IF     LST_INS_INVESTIGATED IS NOT NULL
   AND LST_INS_INVESTIGATED.COUNT > 0
```

is never true so nothing within the `IF - END IF` block is ever executed.

You declared it as

```
LST_INS_INVESTIGATED  RC_INS_INVESTIGATED;
```

but `lst_ins_investigated` doesn't contain anything, it is just *declared*, never *populated* with any values. Once you fix that, code might work.

Comment: I made a update in my question about the way the lst_ins_investigated got data. Please help me, i think maybe is something im forgetting about the instancing of the lst. thanks

Comment: No, it never got any data. PIN_INS_INVESTIGATION got it, but you don't use it in the procedure so that's in vain.

Comment: You were right. i just erased that line and it worked. Thanks bro